# How to store custom css in external css file for JqGrid

Tags: css, jqgrid, pager

I am working on jqGrid. I tried to apply some custom style on jqGrid pager and it is working fine when I put them in style tag of html. Something like given below.

```
<style>
.ui-paging-pager {
        background-color: white !important;
}
</style>
```

But, when I store them externally in .css file, it is not working. I have created customPager.css file, in which I have stored all the css code for pager and used the path of the css file in html file link.
Can someone tell me where am I wrong and How to store custom css in external file for JqGrid?

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles or those in `<style>` tags within a document will automatically override externally defined style rules.

However to override a style in an external stylesheet you need to give the rule you define in your own stylesheet a higher specificity. You can do that by including the parent elements in the selector. For example:

```
#container .foo > .bar .ui-paging-pager {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Also note that the `!important` rule should be avoided for this reason.

Comment: understood but .ui-paging-pager class is already jqgrid css file which is stored externally.

Comment: Sorry, my wording wasn't clear. I mean overriding from *your own* external stylesheet

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without overriding as that external css file is being used by other pages too.

Comment: That's fine. This will only affect the page you load this CSS rule in to. Just to be clear, you should ***not*** amend the jqGrid stylesheet, but to add your own one. I've edited the question wording again to make that clearer.